# Computed property: different types between get and set

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, computed-properties

I want to map ranges of float to strings. In details I would like to convert the degree direction of wind for example, in the corresponding string with the cardinal direction: 220 -> SW

It is possible to create a computed property declared of type `Float` with the custom `get` declaration in order to return the corresponding `String`? In this way I will write it as `Float` but I will read it as `String`.

Something like:

```
var windDirection: Float? {
    get {
        switch self.windDirection {
        case 348.75..<11.25:
            return "N"
            break
        ...
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    set (newValue) {
        self.windDirection = newValue
    }
}
```

If not, what possibilities do I have to produce the same behaviour?

Comment: I'd love to see the answer, too, but I honestly hope that the answer is a resounding "no" :-)

Comment: The answer **is** no, you actually need a `ValueTransformer`

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know this is impossible.
A computed property is still a property which can only be of a single type.

That said, perhaps you'd be better by having your own type for this:

```
struct WindDirection {
    var degrees: Float
    var stringValue: String {
        get {
            // compute the correct string here
            return "\(degrees)"
        }
        set {
            // compute the correct float value here
            degrees = Float(newValue) ?? 0
        }

    }
}

var windDirection: WindDirection
```

If you don't want to use your own type, then you'll have to stick with 2 different properties.

Comment: This is a much better way to handle the situation.

Comment: BTW: you would get more benefit by conforming to `CustomStringConvertible` and renaming `stringValue` to `description`.

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe you can use enum like this way

```
enum Wind {
    case degree(Float)
    case direction(String)
}

extension Wind {

    init?(degree: Float) {
        switch degree {
        case 11.25..<385:
            self = .direction("N")
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }

}

let wind = Wind(degree: 100) // Result is direction("N")
```

Comment: Note that pattern matching against `11.25..<385` will yield `N` (north) for any value in the range `[11.25, 385.0)`, i.e. `180`, which is way south :)

Comment: Yeah, I don't notice that

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this! Do not do this!! Never ever ever do this. I don't have the words to explain how bad of an idea this is.

```
private var _windDirection: Float?

var windDirection: Any? {
    get {
        guard let windDirection = _windDirection else {
            return nil
        }

        switch windDirection {
        case 348.75..<11.25:
            return "N"
        ...
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
    set (newValue) {
        guard let windDirection = newValue as? Float else {
            _windDirection = nil
            return
        }

        _windDirection = windDirection
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*(You should have a look at conformance to `CustomStringConvertible`, but for the technical discussion, here follows ...)*

You *could*, however implement an `enum` wrapper where each case wraps different types of associated values (much like `Optional<Int>` wraps `.none` or `.some(Int)`).

```
enum WindDirection {
    case asDegree(Float)
    case asString(String)
}
```

With this, you could let your instance variable `windDirection` be a wrapper of two different wrapped types, which would allow you to expect one wrapped type in the setter and return another wrapper type in the getter. E.g.:

```
class Foo {
    private var _windDirection: WindDirection
    var windDirection: WindDirection {
        get {
            switch _windDirection {
            case .asDegree(let angle):
                switch(angle) {
                case 348.75..<360.0, 0..<11.25: return .asString("N")
                case 11.25..<33.75: return .asString("NE")
                /* ... */
                case _ : return .asString("Not expected")
                }
            case _ : return .asString("Not expected")
            }
        }
        set (newValue) {
            if case .asDegree(_) = newValue {
                _windDirection = newValue
            }
        }
    }

    init?(_ windDirection: WindDirection) {
        guard case .asDegree(_) = windDirection else { return nil }
        _windDirection = windDirection
    }
}
```

Example usage (you would need to handle the unwrapping of the wrapped associated value at call to your instance property, however)

```
// attempt initialization
if let foo = Foo(.asDegree(11.0)) {

    // getter
    if case .asString(let windDirection) = foo.windDirection {
        print(windDirection) // N
    }

    // setter
    foo.windDirection = .asDegree(15.75)

    // getter
    if case .asString(let windDirection) = foo.windDirection {
        print(windDirection) // NE
    }
}
```